# Encrypted root with a detached header in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, initramfs, cryptsetup, cryptroot

I am trying to setup an encrypted root with a detached header in Ubuntu 20.04

I was able to get it to work successfully in Ubuntu 18.04. I created the file: **/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/cryptroot** with

```
target=root,source=/dev/disk/by-partuuid/12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012,rootdev,discard,header=/etc/12345678.luks.header,key=none
```

So I made a similar file in Ubuntu 20.04. But when I enter my password during booting, I get the message:

> ERROR: ROOT: cryptsetup failed, bad password or options?

I've tried all sorts of subtle variations and I'm really stuck. Development seems to be going on [here](https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cryptsetup/tree/debian/initramfs) but there isn't enough (public?) discussion so I cant understand what's changed.

I checked to confirm that **/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/cryptroot** is still copied across into my initramfs. I don't believe the initramfs is actually reading the **cryptroot** at all because if I add additional options such as "tries=8" I still only get the default three attempts.

Does **/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/cryptroot** still exist for setting options? Has it been moved somewhere else? Is there a completely different method I should be using now?

Thanks for reading. I hope someone can shed some light on this.

Answer (score 1):

With detached headers the disks don’t usually have a partuuid for crypt to lock on to, full disk anyway which I’m assuming your using for root.

Have you tried aiming your source as /dev/disk/BY-ID/ as that is how mine is set up.